# Why is TRY_CAST only working for some records

Tags: t-sql, datetime, try-catch

I have used a TRY_CAST on a Varchar field where dates are stored (I know bad practice but nothing I can control).

The value 12/05/2018 04:30 is being outputted as 2018-12-05 04:30:00.000 which is incorrect as here in the UK 12/05/2018 is 12th May, however the TRY_CAST is outputting a value of 5th Dec.

The TRY_CAST isn't returning any value for 29/05/2018 07:00 (29th May) as I assume it thinks its 5th of the 29th Month which doesn't exists.

```
,TRY_CAST([Time decision made for caesarean section].VALUE as datetime)
    AS DECISION_FOR_CAESAREAN_SECTION_DATE_TIME
```

The field above is what I am trying to output

Below is some sample data from of the original stored values, all of which are UK (May) dates.

```
22/05/2018 07:30
12/05/2018 04:30
22/05/2018 00:51
16/05/2018 10:08
21/05/2018 13:03
17/05/2018 11:53
21/05/2018 14:22
29/05/2018 07:00
```

What is the best method to output these as valid UK datetimes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TRY_CONVERT which offers the style option that TRY_CAST doesn't

```
SELECT 
   TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '12/05/2018 04:30', 103), 
   TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '22/05/2018 07:30', 103),
   TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'gbn', 103)
```

Style 103 affects the date part only.

Alternatively, you can use SET DATEFORMAT dmy first

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SELECT
    TRY_CAST('12/05/2018 04:30'AS datetime),
    TRY_CAST('22/05/2018 07:30'AS datetime),
    TRY_CAST('gbn'AS datetime);
```

Comment: So is it fair to say that `TRY_CONVERT` won't automatically do all the work for you regarding figuring out the mask of the input?  It seems slightly counterintuitive that we still have to feed it the mask number +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If the system would guess the mask (from culture configuration?), this might work on your machine, but breaks in production (or even worse: works for a while with wrong data). We should *never-ever* rely on culture dependant formats... (and hope that the system will guess the right mask...)